# Which protocols can a soap web service use?

Tags: jakarta-ee, soap, jax-ws

I am new to soap web services and was able to write a soap web service and test it.

I understood that soap uses HTTP/HTTPS to communicate. However when I was browsing through websphere admin console I saw something called soap connector and the port number was 8880. What does this mean?

Comment: ports are mostly irrelevant. 80 is the default for http, but you don't HAVE to use 80. you can run an http server on any port you want.

Comment: No i am not asking about the port. I want to know what is soap connector? How and where can I use it?

Comment: The soap connector is a piece of software between the client and the SOAP web services. It has own API which helps the client to configure the communication with the SOAP web services. You can see detailed description on the Oracle example: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/mobilecs_gs/MCSUA/GUID-A5CCD158-4977-4051-A8D8-5E2BECB2B6A8.htm#MCSUA-GUID-A5CCD158-4977-4051-A8D8-5E2BECB2B6A8

Answer (score 1):

Answer : [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) ;-)

and under, for transport layer : HTTP or HTTPS.

SOAP_CONNECTOR_ADDRESS default value 8880 is a specific port opened on your appserver for web service dialog only (not serving web pages for example).

[IBM WebSphere doc about ports](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.migration.nd.iseries.doc/ae/rmig_portnumber.html)

Kenavo! (in BZH),

Yoann